# Upgrade Ubuntu 12.10 >>> Ubuntu 13.04 Black Screen Boot Failed with Nvidia Geforce Gt630 WHY?

Tags: boot, nvidia, 13.04, do-release-upgrade

1) I downloaded the iso of ubuntu desktop 64bit.
2) I burned the iso.
3) I tried to start the installation of ubuntu 13.04 from DVD

Black screen Black screen Black screen

4) http://www.ashwinraon.com/2012/08/how-to-solve-ubuntu-blank-screen-boot/
or http://ubuntuguide.net/no-input-signal-and-boots-into-blank-screen-after-ubuntu-installation
“Press and hold down Shift key from Bios screen until see the Grub menu. Highlight the first entry, press “e” to edit it. Navigate to words “quiet splash”, delete them and type “nomodeset” in their place (without quotes). Press Ctrl + X to continue boot.”

5) I ran the installation but after rebooting >>>> Black Screen

6) “Press and hold down Shift key from Bios screen until see the Grub menu. Highlight the first entry, press “e” to edit it. Navigate to words “quiet splash”, delete them and type “nomodeset” in their place (without quotes). Press Ctrl + X to continue boot.”

7) Boot ok. Ubuntu 13.04 started.
8) I installed drivers Nvidia 313.30 certified with Synaptic.
9) I created the file / etc/X11/xorg.conf for resolution 1980x1020 (Samsung SyncMaster PX2370)

With Ubuntu 12.04 & Ubuntu 12.10 installation no boot problem no Black Screen.
Also directly upgrading Ubuntu 12.10 (sudo apt-get update   sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo update-manager -d)  I had the same problem

Someone can explain why all this is happening?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happened... you are TEMPORARILLY modifying the grub boot parameters.
You need to permanently modify them. 
So you need to add nomodeset to your 
/etc/default/grub/

I will assume you are using Ubuntu with unity for my example:
Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

look for the line that says:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
and change it too:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
Then, (VERY IMPORTANT) save the file and run this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot without troubles!