# I can't install Ubuntu 13.04 on a new computer

Tags: installation, boot, ati, graphics, 13.04

I managed to install Ubuntu 13.04 by disabling "Virtualization Technology" in my BIOS (which I believe let's me operate several OS's) and changing in GRUB2 `quiet splash` to `quiet splash nomodeset`.

However, when I reboot after installation (I installed the third party software), **my screen will start blinking again**. So I again changed the command `quiet splash` to `quiet splash nomodeset` but now I end up in what I believe is the terminal. But I do not know how to proceed from here.

My computer is a Toshiba Satellite S855-S5170 and I attribute this problem to the dual graphics card (AMD Radeon HD 7670M Graphics 2GB DDR3)

UPDATE 27/04/13

I changed 'quiet splash' to 'nomodeset' as it was suggested, but I did the same thing (i end up in the terminal) Then (inside the terminal) I tried 'startx' but it says that '[KSM] drm report modesetting isnt supported' 'fatal error: no screens found' What can I do now? Thanks for the support.

Comment: What happens if you run the "startx" command in the terminal? Does this fix the problem on reboot?

Comment: `I managed to install Ubuntu 13.04 by disabling "Virtualization Technology" in my BIOS` What happened before that? `I installed the third party software` What software did you install and why?

Comment: Try looking at this link, I had a similar problem:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/286062/upgrade-ubuntu-12-10-ubuntu-13-04-black-screen-boot-failed-with-nvidia-gefor According to me there is a syntax error: **you need to replace quiet splash to nomodeset**. You have to instead replaced quiet splash quiet splash nomodeset Right?

Comment: @Alex I checked the "Install third party software" during Ubuntu 13.04 installation process

Comment: @somoso I tried startx but it gives the error I described above.

Comment: @angelohp I changed 'quiet splash' to 'nomodeset' as you said but it seems I end up in the same place. Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Have you tried running "sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup"? What this command does is backs up your xorg.conf file (the one that sets up x-server) and then once you reboot, your system will generate a brand new xorg.conf file. Hopefully that should fix things. If not, then run "sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup /etc/X11/xorg.conf"

Answer (score 0):

Try `startx` to start GUI from a terminal.